# How to send an error message to the Debugger and stopping the debug?

Tags: c#, debugging, attributes

I want to check some conditions in my code and if the condition not satisfied I want show an error on the Debug when the VS(C#) errors shown,
I tried to do that with `Debug.Assert()` but it didn't work like what I expected.
this is my code:

```
  public class Inflicted : Attribute
    {
        public string[] Names{ get; set; }
        public Inflicted (params string[] Names) {

            // check if the params empty;
            // so show the error in debuger.
            Debug.Assert(Names.Length == 0, "The Inflicted cant be with zero argument");

            this.Names= Names;
        }
}
```

when I use this attribute without any arguments my project build successfully

```
// ...
[Inflicted]
public string Title
{
    get { return _Title; }
    set { _Title = value;}
}
// ...
```

but I want the user of this attribute can't use my attribute only with arguments.
looks like: `[Inflicted("param1", "param2")]`

Comment: Do you expect an error during debug or during compilation?

Comment: @WillemDuncan yes i want to causing compilation error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a compile error, `Debug.Assert` is not for you: it creates errors when running the application in debug.

To create an error on compilation, you should change your constructor:

```
public Inflicted (string param1, params string[] otherParams) {

}
```

Since the `params` argument can be empty, this will force calls to the constructor to have at least 1 argument.